# Alternativa a CXGrid de Dev-Express

Tags: delphi-2010

Estoy trabajando por un proyecto en mi trabajo en el cual recurren mucho a lo que serian los componentes Dev-Express y estoy buscando la forma de reemplazar estos componentes para poder prescindir de ellos y así no seguir pagando la suscripción del componente, pero me encontré con el CXGrid el cual posee muchas características de uso cotidiano en la empresa.

Por mas que busque reemplazos para el CXgrid no encontré nada similar.

Conocen alguna herramienta que ofrezca algo similar?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los más "parecido" que conozco es el [TMS Grid Pack de TMS](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/gridpack.asp), pero también son de pago. 
Otra cosa es que revises si el precio/suscripción es más asequible.

Pero ya te digo que gratis no vas a encontrar nada similar a las DevExpress, por características, soporte, calidad,...

Comment: Estuve realizando pruebas y la verdad me resulto muy útil la herramienta, veré para adquirirla. Gracias!